# Retain the first occurrence and remove the remaining repeating values from a specific column without deleting the entire row in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

My apologies if I cannot state my question properly.

I have a data whose first 20 rows are shown below:

| Structure_no | Name | Structure_type | No. of Spans | Main Span Flag | Name_1 | Proximity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0087X | MainStreet | Bridge | 3 |  |  |  |
| 00010 | Simon | Bridge | 2 |  |  |  |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | Y | Clifton | ON |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | N | Clifton | ON |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | N | Clifton | ON |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | Y | Fraser | UNDER |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | N | Fraser | UNDER |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | N | Fraser | UNDER |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 3 | Y | Hawks Bay | ON |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 3 | N | Hawks Bay | ON |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 3 | N | Hawks Bay | ON |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 6 | N | Hamilton | UNDER |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 6 | N | Hamilton | UNDER |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 6 | Y | Hamilton | UNDER |
| 89500 | Spill Sade | Bridge | 2 | Y | Creek | ON |
| 89500 | Spill Sade | Bridge | 2 | N | Creek | ON |
| 89500 | Spill Sade | Bridge | 7 | N | Egerton R | UNDER |
| 89500 | Spill Sade | Bridge | 7 | N | Egerton R | UNDER |
| 01764 | Fort Orban | Bridge | 2 | N | Dockyard | ON |
| 01764 | Fort Orban | Bridge | 2 | Y | Dockyard | UNDER |

What I want is a SQL Query which can retain the first value and remove the remaining repeating values in 'Name_1' column and 'Proximity' column so that my data should look like the following:

| Structure_no | Name | Structure_type | No. of Spans | Main Span Flag | Name_1 | Proximity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0087X | MainStreet | Bridge | 3 |  |  |  |
| 00010 | Simon | Bridge | 2 |  |  |  |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | Y | Clifton | ON |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | N |  |  |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | N |  |  |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | Y | Fraser | UNDER |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | N |  |  |
| 11010 | Simon | Bridge | 4 | N |  |  |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 3 | Y | Hawks Bay | ON |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 3 | N |  |  |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 3 | N |  |  |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 6 | N | Hamilton | UNDER |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 6 | N |  |  |
| 20666 | Canal Lane | Bridge | 6 | Y |  |  |
| 89500 | Spill Sade | Bridge | 2 | Y | Creek | ON |
| 89500 | Spill Sade | Bridge | 2 | N |  |  |
| 89500 | Spill Sade | Bridge | 7 | N | Egerton R | UNDER |
| 89500 | Spill Sade | Bridge | 7 | N |  |  |
| 01764 | Fort Orban | Bridge | 2 | N | Dockyard | ON |
| 01764 | Fort Orban | Bridge | 2 | Y | Dockyard | UNDER |

This data is extracted using the following SQL query:

```
WITH prox AS

(
    SELECT * 
    
    FROM
    (   
        SELECT 
            structure_id,
            name,
            row_number() OVER (partition by name order by name) AS name_repetition,
            proximity_code
    FROM 
    feature_table
)

where name_repetition >=1

)

SELECT 
    a.STRUCTURE_NO, 
    a.NAME,
        a.STRUCTURE_TYPE,
    a.number_of_spans,
        d.main_span_flag,
        e.NAME,
        e.PROXIMITY_CODE
    
FROM

    STRUCTURE a
    Inner Join STRUCTURE_STATUS b ON a.structure_status_tp=b.structure_status_tp
    left join span d on a.structure_id=d.structure_id
    LEFT JOIN prox e ON a.STRUCTURE_ID = e.STRUCTURE_ID
```

As you can see that I did try to use CTE but it deletes the entire row which I do not want.

There are some structures that are repeated several times but have null values in both 'Name_1' and 'Proximity' columns. These can be ignored.

The query I want, should be affecting those two specific columns where there are repeating values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as to how I can achieve the requirement.

I use Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and then a `CASE` expression to show the values only when the row number is `1`.

```sql
SELECT STRUCTURE_NO, 
       NAME,
       STRUCTURE_TYPE,
       number_of_spans,
       main_span_flag,
       CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN name1 END AS name1,
       CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN PROXIMITY_CODE END AS proximity_code
FROM   (
  SELECT a.STRUCTURE_NO, 
         a.NAME,
         a.STRUCTURE_TYPE,
         a.number_of_spans,
         d.main_span_flag,
         e.NAME AS name1,
         e.PROXIMITY_CODE,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY a.structure_no, e.name
           ORDER BY d.main_span_flag DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   STRUCTURE a
         INNER JOIN STRUCTURE_STATUS b
         ON a.structure_status_tp = b.structure_status_tp
         LEFT OUTER JOIN span d
         ON a.structure_id=d.structure_id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN feature_table e
         ON a.STRUCTURE_ID = e.STRUCTURE_ID
)
```

Note 1: In SQL, result sets are non-deterministically ordered so you will need to provide an `ORDER BY` clause. I chose `main_span_flag` in `DESC`ending order so that the `Y` values were before `N`; you will need to work out what `ORDER BY` clause meets your requirements because your expected output does not have any obvious criteria that can be used to get your desired order.

Note 2: Your query uses `ROW_NUMBER` and then filters when the row number is `>= 1` but this will always be true so appears to be a pointless operation that can be removed.

Comment: Thanks so much Sir!! The code did exactly what I wanted.